# How google crawl my website pages if user name and password is needed

Tags: web-crawler, fetch

Hello I am using **Fetch As Google** option provided in **Google's webmaster tools** but when I fetch some page and I hold the cursor on the submitted result it shows my login page instead of the page which I submitted. So I am wondering if there is a problem for Google to crawl password protected websites and also is there any option to attach some crawl script to my page just like I'm doing with **Google Analytics**.

Comment: Just an idea: Do you really need a login system if you're letting Googlebot in?

Comment: Social networks need login :)

Answer (score 0):

Just had an client who wanted me to solve the same problem.

I believe this is what your are looking for: https://www.google.com/adsense/app#sitepermissions.

Here, you can give google's crawler a user name and password (even more if needed).